# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, radicals

A student was recently asked this question by his instructor:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)}$$

Converge or diverge?

I feel a little dumb for not being able to answer it. The following tests fail to prove convergence or divergence:

nth term test for divergence (limit is 0), ratio test (limit is 1), root test (see ratio test), limit comparison with $\sqrt[n]{n}$ (not sure why I thought that'd work)

Something I did try was using the fact that

$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\cdots+x^2y^{n-3}+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})\;,$$

to rewrite $\sqrt[n]{n}-1$ as

$$\frac{n-1}{n^{1-1/n}+n^{1-2/n}+\cdots+n^{2/n}+n^{1/n}+1}\;.$$

However, I'm not sure what to compare this to. According to wolfram alpha this series "diverges by the comparison test", but comparison to what? There is a similar problem in Baby Rudin, but for $(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$, and a simple nth root test resolves that series [convergence] in a hurry. Any ideas? Have any of you encountered a similar looking series before? Thanks.

Comment: In addition to the nice answers you received, you can do a quick check on WolframAlpha (Sum[n^(1/n) - 1,{n,1, Infinity}]) and it tells which tests it tried and which work to show divergence. Of course, you still need to determine why, but that might prove useful at times.

Answer (score 20):

Rewrite $\sqrt[n]{n}$ as $n^{1/n}=e^{(\ln n)/n}$ and use $e^x-1\sim x$ to see that
$$ \sqrt[n]{n}-1\sim \frac{\ln n}{n} $$
(where I use $\sim$ to mean “is asymptotically equal to”). Now compare with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 5):

A variation on Harald's answer. For all real $x>0$ and integral $n \geq 1$ $$\log(x) \leq n(x^{1/n} - 1)$$ and in particular $$ \frac{\log(n)}{n} \leq n^{1/n} - 1.$$ So it is a divergent series.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For any $k\in \{1,2,...,n\}$ it holds that $n^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\ge n^{1-\frac{k}{n}}$. Because of that:
$$n^{2-\frac{1}{n}}=n\cdot n^{1-\frac{1}{n}} \ge n^{1-\frac{1}{n}}+ n^{1-\frac{2}{n}}+\dots+ n^{\frac{1}{n}} +1$$
Then:
$$\sqrt[n]{n}-1=\frac{n-1}{n^{1-\frac{1}{n}}+ n^{1-\frac{2}{n}}+\dots+ n^{\frac{1}{n}} +1}\ge \frac{n-1}{n^{2-\frac{1}{n}}} \sim \frac{n}{n^{2-\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}\ge \frac{1}{n}$$
Then using comparison tests (both direct and limit comparison test) the series diverges.